# Ionic/Capacitor React App API Requests returning HTML on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

#### The current behavior:

All API requests to the localhost server are returning the index.html file of the React.js app on the iOS build, but requests work fine on browser and PWA builds.

#### The expected behavior:

Requests return the intended data (usually JSON).

---

#### Details

Typically, API requests go to http://localhost:3000/api/[route]. In the iOS build, they are going to capacitor://localhost/api/[route]

Because the route is returning HTML and not JSON data, I am getting the following error (one of many, as each API route, has the same error) which causes a white screen:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...a.map...')
```

I tried adding a hostname (location where the production server is hosted) to the capacitor.config.json file in my root directory, but it still fails. Dev API server is running on localhost:3000.

Tried setting the server hostname to "localhost:3000" in the config as well.

```
"server": {
    "hostname": "localhost:3000"
  },
```

"http" is not allowed as a iosScheme as mentioned in the docs for the capacitor config:
**Can't be set to schemes that the WKWebView already handles, such as http or https](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/2875766-seturlschemehandler)**

Because the site works on every other build other than this iOS build, the issue should be here...

How can I route my requests on the iOS build to direct to the correct location?

#### Update

If I set the server.url option in the capacitor.config.json file to https://www.website.com, I'm able to pull data from my production server, but when the authorization check returns a 401, the app seems to hang on the splash screen and the only error-like message I get in the console is that the response returned a 401 (as expected)

Device console output: [image: Device console output]

XCode console output: [image: Xcode console output]

Comment: we are going to need a bit more information here to provide any support

Comment: What information do you need? The server is returning the correct data in browser, but for the iOS build the iosScheme of capacitor seems to be the issue as HTTP isn't allowed. @AaronSaunders

Comment: what is the server that is running on local host? and unless you have a server running on your phone, you will need to redirect to another address to get the api to work

Comment: I have a production server running on a globally hosted site that works for the live version of the webapp (ex: website.com/api/[route]) as well as a dev server hosted on localhost. As mentioned, changing the hostname to either website.com or localhost:5000 in the config and building out the app again does not work. Server is built with express.js and works perfectly fine for everything except this iOS build.

Comment: you will need to provide some more code than the little you provided, perhaps an example where you changed the host address and it did not work.

Comment: @AaronSaunders Added the json from the config file. It didn't work from autogeneration and as what is shown above. Also as mentioned above, adding an iosScheme of "http" isnt allowed. Info is gathered from here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Comment: you should add your http call consumption code.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib It's an http call using axios to my API route, typically in a redux action or a function within a useEffect hook. These work on every platform though, so it has to be something with the iOS app/ionic/capacitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue was fixed by setting the server.url parameter in the capacitor.config.json file to the URL of the production server:

```
"server":{
    "url":"https://www.website.com"
}
```

Second issue was making sure the splash screen hide code from @capacitor/splash-screen was actually deployed onto prod in the index.js file.

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';
setTimeout(() => {
  SplashScreen.hide();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

By the little information you have provided I'll try to guess what's wrong.

1. You are using relative urls instead of absolute urls. If you make a XHR/fetch call to `/api/[route]`, the browser will append the scheme and host name to it and will turn it into `capacitor://localhost:3000/api/[route]`. That url belongs to the app, not to the web server where you API is running.
2. You are using localhost, localhost means "this machine", if you run the app in a browser or iOS simulator, localhost is the machine where the browser and simulator and browser are running, and the local server is also running on the same machine, so they don't have any problem accessing it. But if you run on a real device, localhost is the device, and the device doesn't have a server running. You should use the local IP (numbers) of the computer where the server is running, and the device should be connected to the same network for being able to access it.
3. Capacitor apps are "affected" by CORS, you need special server configurations to allow the connections https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors.

Looks like you are on the point 1, once you fix it you'll hit point 2 and then probably point 3 after that.

Comment: As mentioned above in the update section, instead of using relative URLs I was able to get data from the production server by setting the server.url config option to the URL of my server. However, the app now hangs on the splash screen without any major errors (consoles shown above)

Comment: Setting the server.url makes no sense, if you set the server url then you are just loading an external site instead of loading the app assets.

Comment: That works great for my use case. In fact, it makes it so I only need to deploy once for all devices.

Comment: It can lead to app rejections, but if you are happy about it